# How do I fix my query level for API calls?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was told by google to seek help here..

In Google Console, under my project, the API key is showing a usage of 326 in the last 30 days, has no restrictions, but shows 100% errors. Under the YouTube Data API v3 portion, I can see that the “Queries per day” is set to 0. This is causing issues on my site. Is the only way to fix this to request a higher quota? Why was it set to 0 anyway? How Can I prevent this again?

Comment: I would first investigate the cause of those errors. Depending on the actual way your app is implemented, upon fixing the errors, you may well not need a quota extension at all. (Take note to the fact that each failed API endpoint call [is accounted](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) exactly as a successfully completed one.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to request a quota extension.  In the quota section of the google developer console

[image]

it will bring you to another page where you can request additional quota

[image]